# ffmpeg on 2x12 Core CPU uses every core but only to 40-70% - where is the bottleneck?

Tags: memory, ffmpeg, video, cpu, performance

I  converted videos with ffmpeg on my Ryzen 3700X and ALL cores were used to 100%. Now I ran the same conversation on a server with 2x Xeon E5-4657L v2 and 192GB RAM. Surprisingly all cores were used, but  nearly none is at 100%. Most of the cores were around 20-70%, which leads to an averange usage of about 40-70% like this:

[image: htop cpu usage]

`iotop --only` shows not more than ~300K/s writes, which is expected since the disk was also barely used on the Ryzen. But I'm wondering why the Xeon is not completely used to speedup the converting process? I won't expect that all 24 cores were used, however I'd expect that at least 8 cores are running at 100% without exception like the Ryzen does.

I also tried to run the same conversation on a SSD (I used a HDD), it's only 1,5 seconds faster.

When it's not the CPU, not the disk, the amount of memory (not more than 4GB of the 192GB are in use), what limits the CPU? Is it the memory speed (1600 Mhz DDR3, read by `sudo lshw -short -C memory`)? The Ryzen system already has DDR4 with 2400 Mhz.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with ffmpeg v4.2.4 on the Xeon server. My example use-case is to convert a H264 video to H265 and adjust the CRF:

```
time ffmpeg -i C0052.MP4 -hide_banner -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 C0052_linux_x265_crf28.mp4
```

I tried using H264, so that just the CRF is changed. The CPU cores are still only used from ~50-70%, the codec doesn't seem to have much influence on that. Just the RAM usage increased from nearly 4GB to 8GB by changing the codec.

Comment: why do you think it should be 100%?  Its maxing at use of all the threads.  Whatever the threads are doing dont require maxing out the cores.

Comment: Cause it's 100% on the Ryzen on all of the 8 cores and 16 threads, so it seems ffmpeg parallelize to use as much CPU as possible for speeding up things.

Comment: You can't just parallelize as much as you want. Frames depend on each other. They also cannot be subdivided endlessly. Additionally, there's RAM and storage bandwidth to consider. You also seem to assume that threads are pinned to cores. They are not.